# Get XMLA Service working with Saiku CE?

Tags: pentaho, mondrian, saiku

I have been using Mondrian as a standalone app, but since Pentaho decided to not ship it completely I find it too hard to install standalone nowadays.

After some research I found Saiku to be a good bundle to get Mondrian up and running smoothly. A big bonus for the REST API, exactly what I need since I am doing a custom frontend on top of the cubes.

However, I also want to connect to the cubes with Excel (with a XMLA Provider). That worked on Mondrian standalone, but I can not get Saikus xmla service to work. I am using the URL http://localhost:8080/saiku/xmla.

This works good in Pentaho BI Server btw, but I would really like to utilize the REST API Saiku got.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?